# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in React+Next.js in production mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tslint

We have giant project in React+Typescript+Next.js.
Build for test and preproduction works,but doesn't work in production.
I get following error in one minified chunk common.345666....js.
(Javascript) - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
It is dificult to find where is error because of size of project.
Interesting that it works if I run on production with command: node server.js
Build for production worked well one month ago.
I used TsLint and compared previous and current version warning -  the same warnings as for previous version.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I randomly see this error as well. Still no solution yet, let me know if you have better update.